# Is there a C# equivalent way for Java InputStream and OutputStream?

Tags: c#, java

I am referring to the source code written in java and it contains **InputStream** and **OutputStream** objects throughout, i wonder if there is a way in C# to create user-predifined InputStream and Outpustream Classes ; if not the java InputStream and OutputStream objects will they have the same functionality if i treat them as a simple Stream object?

Comment: See [this](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/CSharp/Web/javapi/biz/ritter/javapi/io/java.io.InputStream.cs.htm) implementation.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is no type-level distinction between in- and out-streams in .NET. Just derive your custom class from `System.IO.Stream` and let the overridden properties [`CanRead`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.canread.aspx) and [`CanWrite`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.canwrite.aspx) return the appropriate values.