# "No content provider" error whenever I attempt to upload a file on Android device

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-storage

Lately I've been having a problem trying to upload a file to storage on Android. It works perfectly fine on the Unity Editor, but whenever I run it on my Android I keep getting this error instead:

> **System.AggregateException: Exception of type 'System.AggregateException' was thrown. 
>   Firebase.Storage.StorageException: No content provider:
>   /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.Comp.App/files/Uploads/ppp/master.json**

Here is the code I use to upload files to storage:

```
Firebase.Storage.StorageReference f_ref = storage_ref.Child(referencePath); 
print("Reference path: " + referencePath); 

// Upload the file 
f_ref.PutFileAsync(filePath) 
.ContinueWith((Task<StorageMetadata> task) => 
{ 
  if (task.IsFaulted || task.IsCanceled) 
  { 
  Debug.Log(task.Exception.ToString()); 
  print("Couldn't upload " + filePath); 
  // Uh-oh, an error occurred! 
  } 
else { 
  Firebase.Storage.StorageMetadata metadata = task.Result; 
  string download_url = metadata.DownloadUrl.ToString(); 
  Debug.Log("download url = " + download_url); 
} 
});
```

The file is stored in a persistent file path that depends on the device. I tried purposefully uploading a non-existing file path and I received a "FileNotFound" exception instead, so I'm certain the path of the file I'm trying to upload is correct.

I would greatly appreciate any help in figuring out what this exception means and how to fix it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Use an `inputStream` and `putStream` instead :

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(filePath);
f_ref.putStream(is).....;
```

Comment: I should mention I'm using Unity. Is there a C# equivalent to Java's FileInputStream?

Comment: Sorry don't see that is Unity3D, please take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119631/is-there-a-c-sharp-equivalent-way-for-java-inputstream-and-outputstream

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should pass an **URI** of the form Like This

> file:///sdcard/yourFilePath

Comment: This doesn't work; this gives a file not found exception instead. The filepaths used are correct anyway since they are retrieved from a list of files in a given directory. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and E. Abdel's answer led me on the right track. I was trying to upload a file saved with a `BinaryFormatter`

```
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    FileStream file = File.Create(Application.persistentDataPath + pathToFile);
    bf.Serialize(file, currentPlayer);
    file.Close();
```

I was getting the exact same error, then I tried a different way of uploading it. Instead of `PutFileAsync`, use `PutStreamAsync`, I guess this needs to be used for serialized files with `BinaryFormatter`.

```
    // File located on disk
    string local_file = Application.persistentDataPath + pathToFile;

    // Create a reference to the file you want to upload
    StorageReference storage_ref = FirebaseStorage.DefaultInstance.RootReference;
    StorageReference player_ref = storage_ref.Child("test");

    Stream stream = new FileStream(local_file, FileMode.Open);
    player_ref.PutStreamAsync(stream).ContinueWith((Task<StorageMetadata> task) =>
    {
        if (task.IsFaulted || task.IsCanceled)
        {
            Debug.Log(task.Exception.ToString());
            // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
        }
        else
        {
            // Success
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case i had the same error (***Firebase.Storage.StorageException: No content provider***) only to upload files with Android.

Reading the E. Abdel's answer I have found these following solution in C# to Unity.

```
    StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(file_path);

    StorageReference storage_ref = storageRef.Child(file_name_to_storage);

    storage_ref.PutStreamAsync(stream.BaseStream)
      .ContinueWith((Task<StorageMetadata> task) => {
          if (task.IsFaulted || task.IsCanceled)
          {
              Debug.Log(task.Exception.ToString());
          }
          else
          {
              Debug.Log("Finished uploading...");
          }
      });
```

It`s works in Unity editor and Android to upload files specifying de file path in my case the file_path is:  /storage/emulated/0/file_name.png

Answer (score 0):

Was having same problem.  Solved it by putting "file://" in front of the uri and parsing it with Uri.parse as:

```
       val uriString = Uri.parse("file://$uri")

       if (metadata != null) {
            fileRef.putFile(uriString, metadata).await()
        } else {
            fileRef.putFile(uriString).await()
        }
```